# JSON responce from REST as string in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a REST service in Angular which returns JSON response. I need to get the response as string to do some pattern matching and value replacement.

I am using Angular 7. Below is my service.

```
getUIData(): Observable<any> {
    const url = `${this.baseUrl}/uiData`;
    return this.http.get<any>(url).pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError<any>('Get Data:'))
    );
  }
```

Comment: Use the `map` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By default **`HttpClient`** will return **JSON** Object

in your case you need to convert it to String. So do some changes like below,

```
getUIData(): Observable<any> {
    const url = `${this.baseUrl}/uiData`;
    return this.http.get<any>(url).map( response => JSON.stringify(response.data)).
      catchError(this.handleError<any>('Get Data:');
  }
```

as @dcg suggested use `map` instead of `pipe` to convert your response data to string in the Service method itself.

I hope it helps :).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two ways :

1)  set request headers as :

```
'Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'
```

2) Transform your response in stringified format inside map operator

```
JSON.stringify(data);
```

Note for second. it will still be JSON but stringified